# Iphones can connect to Bluetooth speakers but MacBooks cant?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth

I have a portable Bluetooth speaker and a Bluetooth enabled amplifier. Mine and my SO's iPhones (5 and 5c) have no trouble connecting to either of these. However, our MacBooks(both Airs, both running Mavericks) can't even detect them.

Is there some setting or some way to make this work?

Comment: Can you please provide details of the portable Bluetooth speaker and your Bluetooth enabled amplifier. Also, can you actually clarify what model iMacs you're using, as _our iMacs (both Airs_ doesn't actually make sense. The actual year/model would be good.

Comment: @Monomeeth the speaker is a Sony SX11 and the amplifier is a Kentiger HY-502s.

Both Airs are 2011 models, so I'm guessing that would make them 4s.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you're talking about two mid-2011 MacBook Air laptops and **not** iMacs?

Comment: @Monomeeth Yeah! Crap, sorry! I meant to type 'MacBook' not 'iMac'!